# Increment Page Index for Paginated Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I have implemented pagination in my app but I am having trouble with incrementing the page index. I am getting data from `unsplash api` and have formed the request url like below:

```
private String url = Constants.SEARCH_URL + "top30&page="+ PAGE_INDEX;
```

and this is the url used below:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=api_key&order_by=latest&query=top30&page=1
```

In my fragment, I have a constant int like `private static int PAGE_INDEX = 1;` which tracks the current page and used for getting the next pages till page limit.

The first request runs fine and when scrolling towards the last item, more items are fetched. However, these items are same as from the first page index and after logging the url, I get the same as in first request like below:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=api_key&order_by=latest&query=top30&page=1
```

I have attached my scroll listener in  recyclerview like this and incremented the  `PAGE_INDEX` but not getting the next page in url but in log cat it shows the page index as 2. Here's the listener attached:

```
top30RV.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(llm) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            PAGE_INDEX = PAGE_INDEX + 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "PIn:\t" + PAGE_INDEX);

            loadNextPage();

        }

        @Override
        protected int getTotalPageCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

    });
```

and my `PaginationScrollListener` class code:

```
public abstract class PaginationScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

LinearLayoutManager llm;

public PaginationScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager llm) {
    this.llm = llm;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    int visisbleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = llm.getItemCount();
    int firstVisibleItemPosn = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()){
        if ((visisbleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosn) >= totalItemCount && firstVisibleItemPosn > 0){
            loadMoreItems();
        }
    }

}

protected abstract void loadMoreItems();

protected abstract int getTotalPageCount();

public abstract boolean isLoading();

public abstract boolean isLastPage();

}
```

in my adapter I have called the method to `addLoadingFooter` and it works but also the progressbar is not dismissed and `removeLoadingFooter` is called but doesn't work because of the page index is less than the page limit.

```
public class Top30Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = Top30Adapter.class.getSimpleName();

private final Context context;
private List<UnsplashImages> itemsList;

private UnsplashImages unsplashImages;

private static final int ITEMS = 0;
private static final int PROGRESS = 1;

private boolean isLoadingAdded = false;
private boolean retryPageLoad = false;

private String errorMsg;

private PaginationAdapterCallback mCallback;

public Top30Adapter(Context context, List<UnsplashImages> itemsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType){
        case ITEMS:
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.wallpaper_items_layout, parent, false);
            return new WallpaperItemViewHolder(view);
        case PROGRESS:
            View pv = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progress_items_layout, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(pv);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewholder, final int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)){
        case ITEMS:
            WallpaperItemViewHolder wallpaperItemViewHolder = (WallpaperItemViewHolder) viewholder;
            unsplashImages = (UnsplashImages) itemsList.get(position);
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(unsplashImages.getRegularImg())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.drawer_header_trimmed)
                    .into(wallpaperItemViewHolder.wallpaperItemImg);

            wallpaperItemViewHolder.favoriteWP_IV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Favorites favorites = new Favorites();
                    favorites.setFavoritesId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                    favorites.setLargeImgURL(unsplashImages.getRegularImg());
                    favorites.setPreviewImgURL(unsplashImages.getRegularImg());
                    favorites.save();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Added to Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            wallpaperItemViewHolder.setWallPaper_TV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);

                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(((UnsplashImages) itemsList.get(position)).getRegularImg())
                            .into(new Target() {
                                @Override
                                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                    try {
                                        wpm.setBitmap(bitmap);
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Your New Wallpaper Has Been Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap Load Failed");
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Could Not Set Wallpaper...Choose Another", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Prep to Load Bitmap");
                                }
                            });

                }
            });
            break;
        case PROGRESS:
            LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) viewholder;
            if (retryPageLoad){
                loadingViewHolder.mErrorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingViewHolder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                loadingViewHolder.mErrorTxt.setText(errorMsg != null
                        ? errorMsg
                        : context.getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown));

            } else {
                loadingViewHolder.mErrorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loadingViewHolder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemsList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return itemsList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == itemsList.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) ? PROGRESS : ITEMS;
}

public void addImage(UnsplashImages images){
    itemsList.add(images);
    notifyItemInserted(itemsList.size() - 1);
}

public void addAllImages(List<UnsplashImages> list){
    for (UnsplashImages images : list){
        addImage(images);
    }
}

public void addLoadingFooter() {
    isLoadingAdded = true;
    addImage(new UnsplashImages());
}

public void removeLoadingFooter(){
    isLoadingAdded = false;

    int position = itemsList.size() - 1;
    UnsplashImages unsplashImages = getItem(position);

    if (unsplashImages != null){
        itemsList.remove(unsplashImages);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

}

private UnsplashImages getItem(int position) {
    return itemsList.get(position);
}

public void showRetry(boolean show, @Nullable String errorMsg){
    retryPageLoad = true;
    notifyItemChanged(itemsList.size() - 1);
    if (errorMsg != null){this.errorMsg = errorMsg; } else { errorMsg = "Can't Fetch Wallpapers Now..."; }
}

}
```

Full fragment code:

```
public class Top30Fragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = Top30Fragment.class.getSimpleName();

private RecyclerView top30RV;

private List<UnsplashImages> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
private Top30Adapter adapter;

private int PAGE_COUNT;
private static int PAGE_INDEX = 1;
private static int PER_PAGE = 20;
private static int CURRENT_PAGE = PAGE_INDEX;

private boolean isLoading = false;
private boolean isLastPage = false;

private String url = Constants.SEARCH_URL + "top30&page="+ PAGE_INDEX;

public Top30Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vtop = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top30, container, false);

    top30RV = vtop.findViewById(R.id.top30RV);
    top30RV.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    top30RV.setLayoutManager(llm);

    if (Utils.isNetwork(getActivity())){
        fetchWallpapers();
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Check Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    adapter = new Top30Adapter(getActivity(), itemsList);
    top30RV.setAdapter(adapter);

    top30RV.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(llm) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            PAGE_INDEX = PAGE_INDEX + 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "PIn:\t" + PAGE_INDEX);

            loadNextPage();

        }

        @Override
        protected int getTotalPageCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

    });

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return vtop;
}

private void loadNextPage() {
    int newIndex = PAGE_INDEX +=1;
    Log.d(TAG, "Next Page:\t" + newIndex);
    Log.d(TAG, "Next Page Index:\t" + newIndex);
    Log.d(TAG, "Next Page URL:\t" + url);
    AndroidNetworking.get(url)
            .setTag("Load Next Top30")
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Next Page Response:\t" + response.toString());
                    if (response != null){

                        isLoading = false;
                        adapter.removeLoadingFooter();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                            JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                            for (int p = 0; p < results.length(); p++){
                                JSONObject items = results.getJSONObject(p);

                                UnsplashImages images = new UnsplashImages();
                                images.setImageId(items.getString("id"));

                                JSONObject urls = items.getJSONObject("urls");

                                images.setRawImg(urls.getString("raw"));
                                images.setFullImg(urls.getString("full"));
                                images.setRegularImg(urls.getString("regular"));
                                images.setSmallImg(urls.getString("small"));
                                images.setThumbImg(urls.getString("thumb"));

                                itemsList.add(images);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                Log.d(TAG, "New List Size:\t" + itemsList.size());

                                if (CURRENT_PAGE != PAGE_COUNT){
                                    adapter.addLoadingFooter();
                                } else {
                                    isLastPage = true;
                                }

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {

                }
            });
}

private void fetchWallpapers() {
//        String url = Constants.SEARCH_URL + "top30&page="+ PAGE_INDEX + "per_page=" + PER_PAGE;
    Log.d(TAG, "Top30 Unsplash URL:\t" + url);

    AndroidNetworking.get(url)
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .setTag("Get Seasons Wallpapers")
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Un-Response:\t" + response.toString());
                    if (response != null){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                            PAGE_COUNT = jsonObject.getInt("total_pages");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Page Count:\t" + PAGE_COUNT);

                            JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                            for (int p = 0; p < results.length(); p++){
                                JSONObject items = results.getJSONObject(p);

                                UnsplashImages images = new UnsplashImages();
                                images.setImageId(items.getString("id"));

                                JSONObject urls = items.getJSONObject("urls");

                                images.setRawImg(urls.getString("raw"));
                                images.setFullImg(urls.getString("full"));
                                images.setRegularImg(urls.getString("regular"));
                                images.setSmallImg(urls.getString("small"));
                                images.setThumbImg(urls.getString("thumb"));

                                itemsList.add(images);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                Log.d(TAG, "List Size:\t" + itemsList.size());

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {

                }
            });
}
```

Is there another way to construct the request url to increment the page index? Thanks.

Comment: Another way use paging library from android jetpack.

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it will require me to change all my code and app architecture

Comment: Any other way? Thanks

Comment: it will be a good change, believe me

Comment: Can you suggest sth in Java? I have seen the codelab and its in Kotlin and I have not used the new architecture yet. Thanks

Comment: there are dozens of articles about paging library on http://medium.com - just ask uncle google